# Django Template not rendering {{ }}

Tags: python, django

I'm not sure where I've gone wrong, but my template is not rendering. I believe I have set all the correct code in the following Python files, but I do not see it rendering. I am using postgresql if that matters:

**urls.py**:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
import jobs.views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', jobs.views.home, name='home')
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**settings.py**:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
    'jobs.apps.JobsConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Job

def home(request):
    jobs = Job.objects
    return render(request, 'jobs/home.html', {'jobs': jobs})
```

**models.py**:

```
from django.db import models

class Job(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'images/')
    summary = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
```

**jobs/templates/jobs/home.html**:

```
<div class="album py-5 bg-light">
    <div class="container">

      <div class="row">
        {% for i in jobs.all %}
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
            <img src="" alt="">
            <div class="card-body">
              <p class="card-text">{{ jobs.summary }}test</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jobs` is a `QuerySet` of `Job` objects, hence it has no `summary` attribute. Here you used `i` as the iterator of `jobs`. It might be better to rename this to `job`, and thus render this with:

```
<div class="album py-5 bg-light">
    <div class="container">

      <div class="row">
        {% for job in jobs.all %}
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
            <img src="" alt="">
            <div class="card-body">
              <p class="card-text">{{ job.summary }}test</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: In my `models.p`y, it passes `models.CharField(max_length = 200)` to summary, so I'm confused what you mean by not summary attribute.

Also, isn't the "i" just a method variable, which can be any variable like we use in Java:
`for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){}`

I changed `"i"` to `"job"` and it still does not render.

Comment: @JasonG: your `jobs` is not a single `Job` object, it is `Job.objects`, so you aim to retrieve `Job.objects.summary`. But that does not make much sense, since a `Job` manager has no `.summary` attribute, only a `Job` *object*.

Comment: Well, scratch that. I changed `i` to `job` and it renders now. I assumed it was a method variable that was destroyed after execution as it is in Java. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @JasonG: as specified in the answer, iterate with `{% for job in jobs.all %}`, and use `{{ job.summary }}`, not `{{ jobs.summary }}`.